# Layout Update XML for category not working - Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2

I want to use the different file for a category but not working.

For that I have change under **Catalog > Categories >  Layout Update XML**

I have check with both arguments and action but not working

**Path of my list File : Magento_Catalog::product/my-own-list.phtml**

Using Action

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/my-own-list.phtml</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Using Argument

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
<arguments>
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/my-own-list.phtml</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/my-own-list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Magento 2 for some reason doesn't allow `<referenceBlock>` as the starting element, but you can bypass this limitation by referencing the parent container.

Comment: I have clear the cache and working fine, thanks

Comment: After adding <referenceContainer> I was still having trouble getting the updates to display in one environment.  Turns out this category data is stored in an index and my cron:run was failing.  Found this when running CLI magento indexer:reindex and layout updated started working.